# NSNumberFormatter bug on iOS 14

Tags: objective-c, ios13, nsnumberformatter, ios14

Seems like there is a bug with `NSNumberFormatter` on iOS14 when your region is set to Cambodia where the amount is being formatted to "1.234,56" which is not the format being used there.

[image]

It was okay on iOS13. I cannot see any references in regards to this change.

Is there any workaround for this?

---

**UPDATE:**
Issue still exists with iOS 14.2

Comment: The currency also changed before/after the amount. Strange. I don't live there, so I don't know if there have been a change, or if it's a fix, or a new bug, but if it's a bug, I wouldn't open a radar.

Comment: FWIW in simulator the screen is similar to your iOS 14 one for iPad and on macos it is similar to your 13.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify the parameters for **NumberFormatter** to suit your needs. Something like this

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
//formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ","
formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator = "."
//by default its 3
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

print(formatter.string(from: 1000000.00))
//Outputs Optional("TND 1,000,000.00")
```